# How do I make my Apple ID sign in request silent?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, sound-volume, two-factor-authentication

Every time I sign in iCloud I receive in iPad a notification to allow login. Thats ok!

What's not okay is that sound so loud. How do I make it elegantly silent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-factor authentication alert follows the volume of `Ringer and Alerts`. It can be adjusted via the hardware volume buttons, although you may have disabled that functionality.

If that is the case, head into **Settings** → **Sounds** and adjust the slider for `Ringer and Alerts`. This will affect the volume of all notifications (including FaceTime call notifications).

If you want to completely silence those alerts, you can:

- Drag the slider all the way down.
- Use your iPad’s hardware **mute switch** (removed starting with iPad Air 2, iPad mini 4, iPad Pro and iPad 5).
- Pull up the **Control Center** and *enable* the crossed-out bell icon.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to silent just the Apple ID sign in request?

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no separate setting for this under **Notifications**.

Comment: I'll vote to have such an option.

Comment: And a side question... the 2fa alert also appears on my mbp, may I remove them from mbp?

Comment: I believe you can, but I'm not near my Mac to check how this would work. You'd be better off asking this in a separate Question for greater visibility.

Comment: Good ideia... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292781/the-2fa-alert-also-appears-on-my-mbp-may-i-remove-it-from-mbp