# Can I remove Two-Factor Authentication Alerts from my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ipad, mac, two-step-authentication

I already get two-factor authentication alerts on my iPhone and iPad. Is it possible to stop them from appearing on my MacBook Pro as well?

Comment: Do you want to remove 2-factor authentication from MB Pro or just the notifications?

Comment: Just the notifications.

Comment: Do you need them stopped or is permanently muted ok?

Comment: If possible, I do not want to be warned on mbp.